# Send Hex Command in python to instruct a machine to execute an order using TCP/IP Protocol

Tags: python, tcp

i am trying to send a Hex commmand "ABBA05B80000AF11" to a machine using TCP/ IP communication , to instruct the machine to execute an order.seems like , the Hex Command i have sent was unable to go through, Can anyone please help me . thank you

```
import socket

import sys

import struct

import time

import binascii


host = '192.168.1.40'

port = 800

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


inputHex = binascii.unhexlify("ABBA05B80000AF11")


try:

       remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
       s.connect((host, port))
except socket.gaierror:

      print('Hostname could not be resolved Exiting')
      sys.exit()


print('Socket connected to ' + host + ' on ip '+remote_ip)

try:
    while True:
        s.send(inputHex)
        print('Message sent Successfully')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('sending')

except socket.error:
        print('send fail')
    `   enter code here`sys.exit()


s.close()
```

Comment: do you own the client? I think we need the client code as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to go through"?  Did it block?  Do you get an error?  Did the client receive it but did not recognise the data?

Comment: I am trying to write a python programme in my Laptop (Client)  to control the Machine ( Server) by sending Hex code. I can't access the code in the Machine side . But i was given a set of " Hex" Instruction in the Manual which can be used to control the Machine by performing certain tasks when it received the " Hex code" from my Laptop (it can be wrtten in any programming Languages).I try to send the Hex Code "ABBA05B80000AF11" to the Machine via TCP/IP. By right if the machine received it , it should reset the System in the Machine,but in reality it did not after i send it.